# how to pass a variable into an regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

I need help to resolve the issue because the code fails due to 
numLength[0]:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function xyz(){
var predefLength = "5,5";
var number = "20";
var numLength = predefLength.split(",");
var result = /^[-+]?\d{0,numLength[0]}(\.\d{0,numLength[1]})?$/.test(number);
document.write(result);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)-constructor, like:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('pattern as a string', 'flags as a string');
```

Or:

```
var result = new RegExp('^[-+]?\d{0,' + numLength[0] + '}(\.\d{0,' + numLength[1] + '})?$').test(number);
```

Comment: Exactly. Regular expression literals can't be concatenated with string literals.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function xyz(){
var predefLength = "5,5";
var number = "20";
var numLength = predefLength.split(",");

var pattern = new RegExp('^[-+]?\\d{0,'+numLength[0]+'}(\\.\\d{0,'+numLength[1]+'})?$');
var result = pattern.test(number);
document.write(result);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

numLength[0] is 5. We can not add evaluation of variable in regular expression. Below code returns true.

```
var result = /^[-+]?\d{0,x}(\.\d{0,5})?$/.test(number);
```