# How do I match a word that has non-word characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am replacing words in a string and I'm trying to match based on `'\b' + myword + '\b'`
However this does not work when `myword` has a non word character on either end.

```
var myword1 = "testword,";
var myword2 = "(testword";
var testString = "<tag>asdftestword, is a (testwordasdf also (testword </tag> (testword, should be replaced everywhere there is a testword,)";

var rx1 = new RegExp(???(myword1) ,'g');
var rx2 = new RegExp(???(myword2) ,'g');
var result1 = testString.replace(rx1, "replacement");
var result2 = testString.replace(rx2, "replacement");
```

I would like the results to be

```
result1 == "<tag>asdftestword, is a (testwordasdf also (testword </tag> (replacement should be replaced everywhere there is a replacement)"
result2 == "<tag>asdftestword, is a (testwordasdf also replacement </tag> replacement, should be replaced everywhere there is a testword,)"
```

Comment: You cannot create a regular expressions this way, not matter which characters `myword` contains. Have a look at [how to pass a variable into an regular expression in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574498/how-to-pass-a-variable-into-an-regular-expression-in-javascript).

Comment: That applies to all punctuation marks, that they're characters other than \b (beginning/end of word). That's normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally figured this out. It looks like it is too complex to do with just a single RegExp I need multiple!

See it in action [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g4f8s/11/)

```
function EscapeRegex(text) {
    if (!RegExp.sRE) {
    var chars = '/.*+?|()[]{}\\'.split('');
    RegExp.sRE = new RegExp('\\'+chars.join('|\\'), 'g');
    }
    return text.replace(RegExp.sRE, '\\$&');
}

function ReplaceWholeWord(subjectString, wordtofind, replacement){
    var escapedWord = EscapeRegex(wordtofind);
    //simplest scenaro, word to find has non-word characters at begining and end - do basic replace
    if(regexIndexOf(escapedWord, '[^\\w]', 0) == 0 && regexLastIndexOf(escapedWord, '[^\\w]', 0) == wordtofind.length - 1){
        subjectString = subjectString.replace(new RegExp(escapedWord, 'g'), replacement);
    }
    //word to find begins with non-wordcharacter
    else if(regexIndexOf(escapedWord, '[^\\w]', 0) == 0){
        var index = regexIndexOf(subjectString, escapedWord+'[^\\w]', index);
        while(index > 0){
            subjectString = subjectString.substring(0, index) + replacement + subjectString.substring(index + wordtofind.length);
            index = regexIndexOf(subjectString, escapedWord+'[^\\w]', index);
        }
    }
    //word to find ends with non-wordcharacter
    else if(regexLastIndexOf(escapedWord, '[^\\w]', 0) == wordtofind.length - 1){
        var index = regexIndexOf(subjectString, '[^\\w]'+escapedWord, index);
        while(index > 0){
            subjectString = subjectString.substring(0, index) + replacement + subjectString.substring(index + myword.length + 1);
            index = regexIndexOf(subjectString, escapedWord+'[^\\w]', index);
        }
    }
    //word is normal
    else{
        var index = regexIndexOf(subjectString,'[^\\w]'+escapedWord+'[^\\w]', index);
        while(index >= 0){
            subjectString = subjectString.substring(0, index + 1) + replacement + subjectString.substring(index + wordtofind.length + 1);
            index = regexIndexOf(subjectString,'[^\\w]'+escapedWord+'[^\\w]', index);
        }
    }
    return subjectString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
testString.replace( new RegExp('\\b'+myword+'\\b','g'), "replacement");
```

However, if `myword` may contain characters that are special in a regex (e.g. parens, periods, brackets, etc.) then you'll need to [escape them first](http://simonwillison.net/2006/Jan/20/escape/):

```
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
  if (!RegExp.sRE) {
    var chars = '/.*+?|()[]{}\\'.split('');
    RegExp.sRE = new RegExp('\\'+chars.join('|\\'), 'g');
  }
  return text.replace(RegExp.sRE, '\\$&');
}

var re = new RegExp('\\b'+RegExp.escape(myword)+'\\b','g');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this. Just use normal string replace:

```
var myword = "testword,";
var testString = "<tag>asdftestword, is a testword</tag> (testword, should be replaced everywhere there is a testword,)";

var result = testString.replace( myword , "replacement");
```

Comment: I need it to ignore `<tag>asdftestword,` http://jsfiddle.net/g4f8s/ yeilds `<tag>asdfreplacement is a testword</tag> (testword, should be replaced everywhere there is a testword,)`

Comment: JavaScript's `String.prototype.replace` only replaces the first occurrence; you must use a regex with the `/g` flag to replace all occurrences. (Or use other silly looping constructs.)

Comment: fixed with a regex global flag `var result = testString.replace( /testword,/g , "replacement");`

Answer (score 0):

```
var rx = new RegExp('\\b' + myword ,'g');
var result = testString.replace(rx, 'replacement');
```